# Set connection string and a database automatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

My WPF application must install on 2 clients and a server computer.on server computer we have SQL Server. When my application is installed on server computer, it should automatically make a server and restore my database on it, and when I put computers on network, connection string should be set automatically.

I know the connection string has this structure

```
data source=ip,port; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; intital catalog=database; user id=sa;password=112233
```

but how can I fill ip and port automatically?

Comment: sql standard port is 1433

Comment: @Alander oh thanks...what about ip...is there any defualt ip?

Comment: If you're using C# and WPF, you should use the native SQL client, and then your connection string should look something like: `server=(name); database=(dbname); user Id=(some user); password=(pwd)` - and you should ***NOT*** be using the `sa` account for your "normal" applications.